# How can I one-hot-encode multiple columns in R that share categories?

Tags: r, one-hot-encoding

Say I have a dataframe with two columns like this:

| Label 1 | Label 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| A | C |
| B | C |
| C | A |

The values of A, B, and C in the first column are the same values of A, B, and C in the 2nd column.  I want the encoding to look like this:

| Label 1 | Label 2 | is_A | is_B | is_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| A | C | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| B | C | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| C | A | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Basically, I just want it to check if a value shows up in either column.  If so, then code a 1, if not then code a 0.

Now, I know I *could* write this using an `if_else`, like this:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(is_A = if_else(label1 == 'A' | label2 == 'A'), 
is_B = if_else(label1 == 'B' | label2 == 'B'), 
is_C = if_else(label1 == 'C' | label2 == 'C'))
```

but I have many different categories and don't want to write out 50+ if_else statements. I've also tried this:

```
encoded_labels <- model.matrix(~ label1 + label2 - 1, data = df)
```

but this creates separate encodings for label1A vs. label2A, etc.  Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in base R you could Try:

```
cbind(df, unclass(table(row(df), unlist(df))))

  Label_1 Label_2 A B C
1       A       B 1 1 0
2       A       C 1 0 1
3       B       C 0 1 1
4       C       A 1 0 1
```

Another way:

```
cbind(df, +sapply(unique(unlist(df)), grepl, do.call(paste, df)))

  Label_1 Label_2 A B C
1       A       B 1 1 0
2       A       C 1 0 1
3       B       C 0 1 1
4       C       A 1 0 1
```

Note that for the `table` you should do:

```
+unclass(table(row(df), unlist(df))>0)
```

This will take into consideration rows that have multiple values

If you want to use `model.matrix`:

```
+Reduce("|", split(data.frame(model.matrix(~values+0, stack(df))), col(df)))
  valuesA valuesB valuesC
1       1       1       0
2       1       0       1
3       0       1       1
4       1       0       1
```